# IISExpress fails with message "failed to translate IP address + Hostname to Site Id"

Tags: iis-express

I have a .NET 4 webservice running on IIS Express 7.5 on a 2008 Server

the service runs fine for a couple of hours or even a day but after some time the process crashes with an error message `failed to translate IP address + Hostname to Site Id` which is displayed red in the console output.

I streamlined the applicationhost.config to only contain a single site and the binding is only to an ip address and localhost but no success.

I use this command line to start IISExpress

```
iisexpress.exe /config:c:\myconfig\applicationhost.config /site:mysite
```

First of all a solution for the error would be great but any information on how to optain more data for this error would also help. I already checked the eventlog but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I upgraded to IISExpress 8 which runs stable now.

I did not know what caused this issue, but I belive it was somehow related to heavy load on the server since to often (but not exclusively) happend during a scheduled backup.